# venv, Flask (and Apache)

Tags: python, flask, python-venv

I have a Flask+Python3 application that I want to run with Apache+mod_wsgi.  What is the right way to activate venv (not virtualenv)?

All of the documentation I've encountered so far only talks about virtualenv.  I'm pretty new to Python, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious.  Also, if there is a reason I should use virtualenv instead of venv, it'd be nice to understand why.

Comment: For most practical purposes, the end user experience between Python 3's `venv` module and Ian Bicking's virtualenv should be the same, so you can use existing references and examples to help you.